# If $P(A) = .5$, $P(B) = .6$, and $P(A \cap B) = .4$, compute $P(B^c|A^c)$.

Tags: probability

$P(A) = .5$
$P(B) = .6$
$P(A \cap B) = .4$

$P(A^c) = 1 - .5 = .5$
$P(B^c) = 1-.6 = .4$
$P(B^c|A^c)$ is computing the probability of $B^c$ given $A^c$

I have this so far: 
$$P(B^c|A^c) = \frac{P(B^c \cap A^c)}{P(A^c)}$$
How do I get the $P(B^c \cap A^c)$ part? It's not $.5 \cdot .4$.

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $P(A^c\cap B^c) = 1-P(A\cup B)$ by DeMorgan's law. Further
$$1-P(A\cup B) = 1-[P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)].$$